# Is it possible to run a MITM attack on WIFI hotspot

Tags: man-in-the-middle

(completely opened hotspot)

Example: can an attacker sniff traffic and credentials from a bar?

Comment: What kind of hotspot? Is it completely open? If not, what kind of encryption is used on the hotspot?

Comment: I think this question suffers from a complete lack of research. Performing a Google search using the title of the question yielded rich results.

Comment: @schroeder the first result basically answers the question verbatim https://i.imgur.com/ct0N8BC.png

Comment: Yes. Decoding it to a meaningful form depends on the nature of the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! If you want, buy yourself a [WiFi Pineapple](https://www.wifipineapple.com/) and you can do the attack yourself.

Comment: Or, he can do it with a laptop if the NIC can do packet injection.

Comment: or for a poorly configured clients just make a clone with BIGGER signal strength =)

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin `iw reg set BO` ;)

Comment: Or learn to do it yourself without buying an overpriced gadget.

Comment: @korockinout13, given the lack of knowledge demonstrated in the question, I figured a pre-packaged solution would be more accessible to him. If he had the capacity to configure a machine to MITM a hotspot, he never would have asked this question.

Comment: Are you talking about "evil" access point?

Comment: An evil access point can do a lot to inject itself as a MITM. It can send deauth packets to the clients, and advertise itself as the real AP.